# Какой вид подчинения в СПП?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

**Человек уединяется, чтобы поплакать, но изначально он не одинок: когда  человек плачет, он просто не хочет, чтобы кто-нибудь был сопричастен его слезам.**

Существует последовательное, параллельное и однородное подчинение.
Думаю, что здесь – параллельное. Правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Человек уединяется, чтобы поплакать, но изначально он не одинок: когда человек плачет, он просто не хочет, чтобы кто-нибудь был сопричастен его слезам.

Предложение сложной структуры разделено на две части, связанные бессоюзной связью, обозначенной двоеточием.

Первая часть: СПП со значением цели и простое предложение связаны союзной связью (союз НО).

Вторая часть: СПП с двумя придаточными, связь параллельная. **Только во второй части можно говорить о видах связи в СПП с несколькими придаточными.**